# What values are returned for callerID once I issue AT+VCID=2 AT command?

Tags: at-command, modem, caller-id

Many modems such as [USRobotics](https://support.usr.com/support/5631/5631-ug/generic.htm) or [Conexant CX930xx](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/files/CX930xx-manual.pdf) need to issue the following command so I can retrieve the incomming call phone number (caller Id):

```
AT+VCID=1
```

But according to the manuals above will recieve the callerId in formatted form. But I can also issue:

```
AT+VCID=2
```

For unformatted form. But in the latter case what output should I expect compared to the formatted form. As far as I know formatted form will return:

```
RING\r\n
DATE=XXX\r\n
TIME=XXX\r\n
NMBR=XXX\r\n
NAME=XXXX\r\n
\r\n
```

(Above ANY Newline is represented with \r\n and not with the text's newline)

But what output should I expect at unformatted form (via issuing `AT+VCID=2`)?

I want to emulate incomming calls from a modem using an arduino or a programm that uses a virtual serial port so I can have a development tool for software that Uses modem for callerId applications.

What I want to emulate is a Conexant CX930xx series modem using an arduino cause I have no actual modem in my hands right now.